# Just a little change and we're talking physical education

Tags: riddle, anagram

> Without a change I wont let you give up.
>
> Though without my e you've made a jump
>
> On Christmas you hear my first two in succession
>
> Hear only my last two and we're talking physical education
>
> Keep only my middles and I'm way overpowered
>
> Yes, without me your heart's been soured.

What am I?

Comment: I put 3 hrs Into trying to get the rhyming scheme I wanted, and it was solved in a jiffy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> HOPE

Without a change I wont let you give up.

> Hope is what keeps you going without giving up. (also, never give up hope.)

Though without my e you've made a jump

> take away the last E -> HOP

On Christmas you hear my first two in succession

> HO HO HO ...

Hear only my last two and we're talking physical education

> PE

Keep only my middles and I'm way overpowered

> OP = over-powered

Yes, without me your heart's been soured.

> without hope your heart is soured indeed.

Comment: Great job.  Nice explanation of every line.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Hope

Without a change I wont let you give up.

> You still hope so don't give up

Though without my e you've made a jump

> Hop

On Christmas you hear my first two in succession

> Ho

Hear only my last two and we're talking physical education

> PE physical education

Keep only my middles and I'm way overpowered

> OP

Yes, without me your heart's been soured.

> Not having hope is not good

Comment: beat ya by 9 seconds?! hehe  great minds think alike

Comment: Both did great, but I have to hand this one to the earliest poster.